# Infinite loop produced when shifting from and pushing in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, infinite-loop

Why does the following code result in an infinite loop?

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
while (arr.length > 0) {
  console.log(arr.shift());
  arr.push(arr.shift());
}
```

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it?

Comment: Why not though? lol ;D

Comment: @DaveNewton In every step I'm removing one element with arr.shift(). Shouldn't the length be 0 at some point?

Comment: I think the expectation is 2 x shift & 1 push = -1

Comment: Guys, console.log removes one element each time.

Comment: @RobinZigmond It should finish, but it doesn't. If you run this on your browser's console it will freeze. It's even the case for ruby.

Comment: you can have `undefined` values in an array, it's not the same as not having any element, and produces a `length`

Comment: The `.push()` operation will *always* add 1 to the length of the array.

Comment: Yes, thanks, just read @Nick's answer and now I see it. One of those things that's obvious when you see it, but isn't instantly obvious for some reason (at least not to me...)

Comment: It would be obvious if you either stepped through it or used the debugger and inspected the array at each step, though.

Comment: True, I'm blaming the fact it's Friday afternoon ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr.shift()` returns `undefined` on an empty array, so once you've shifted out the last original number, you'll get `undefined`, which you then push back into the array, so the array never reaches a length of zero.

Answer (score 4):

The last thing you do in the loop is add an item to the array, meaning the array length will always be at least 1. I.e., `arr.length > 0` always evaluates to `true`.

**Edit**: Adding an example to show what's going on. Eventually, `arr.shift()` evaluates to `undefined` when there's nothing left in the array, and then you're pushing `undefined` back into to array, making the array's length 1 element long. See the console output below.

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let i = 0;

while (arr.length > 0 && i < 50) {
  arr.shift();
  arr.push(arr.shift());
  console.log(arr);
  i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: why people put minus here, it is true, `arr.push(arr.shift())` is adding `undefined` in the array, and therefore the array is always 1-lengthy